# eras conversion to ONNX

Tags: python, tensorflow, unity-game-engine, keras, onnx

I have my trained keras model and I am trying to convert it into ONNX format to use it in Unity but I constantly get errors anyone could help:

`import tensorflow.keras as keras
import onnx
import keras2onnx

model = keras.models.load_model('b_model.h5')
onnx_model = keras2onnx.convert.convert(model, model.name)
onnx.save_model(onnx_model, 'onnx_model.onnx')`

The error is as follow: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.keras' has no attribute 'applications' I have all installations updated etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keras2onnx is deprected.

Please use [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx)